# Lagrange's Theorem ($f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$) problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let's consider function $f(x) = \sqrt[4]{x}$ on the interval $[a,b]$ with $a,b > 0$. Find point $c \in (a,b)$, for which the condition of the Lagrange Theorem holds. (Don't forget to check that the found point is inside of $[a,b]$).

So the Lagrange condition is the following: $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$.

I have found the solution like this:

$$\sqrt[4]{b}-\sqrt[4]{a} = \frac{1}{4 c^{3/4}}(b-a)$$

Which leads me to the following solution:

$$\frac{(b-a)^{4/3}}{(1/4)^{4/3}(b^{1/4}-a^{1/4})^{4/3}}$$

And this apparently is not a correct answer. Plus I have not checked that this point is in $(a,b)$.

Here is how you check:

$$a = \left(\frac{(\sqrt[4]{a} + \sqrt[4]{a})(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{a})}{4}\right)^{4/3} < \left(\frac{(\sqrt[4]{a} + \sqrt[4]{b})(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})}{4}\right)^{4/3} < \left(\frac{(\sqrt[4]{b} + \sqrt[4]{b})(\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{b})}{4}\right)^{4/3} = b$$

Comment: Should be $4$ in denominator, not $1/4$.

Comment: For $c\in(a,b)$, $f$ is concave, $f'$ is decreasing, and $f'(a)>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>f'(b)$, so by IVT applied to $f'$, $c$ must be between $a$ and $b$. Doing it by algebra looks tricky...

Comment: thanks @NicolasFRANCOIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative is $f'(x)=x^{-3/4}/4$, so the point $c$ satisfies
$$
4\frac{b^{1/4}-a^{1/4}}{b-a}=c^{-3/4}
$$
Note that the solution is unique. Raise both sides to the power $-4/3$ and find
$$
c=\left(\frac{b-a}{4(b^{1/4}-a^{1/4})}\right)^{\!4/3}
$$
Your computation is indeed correct.

There is no need to prove that $a<c<b$, because Lagrange's theorem tells us this holds.

If you have to go with the torture, set $u=a^{1/4}$, $v=b^{1/4}$ and prove that
$$
\left(\frac{v^4-u^4}{4(v-u)}\right)^{\!4/3}<v^4
$$
which becomes
$$
\frac{v^4-u^4}{4(v-u)}<v^3
$$
that is,
$$
v^3+uv^2+u^2v+u^3<4v^3
$$
Let $u/v=w$, so $0<w<1$. Then the inequality becomes
$$
w^3+w^2+w-3<0
$$
The polynomial factors as $(w-1)(w^2+w+3)$ and the latter factor has no roots. So the only root is $1$ and the polynomial assumes negative values for $w<1$.

Do similarly for the inequality $c>a$.